# Aggregate daily sales data at monthly level for each customer

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to rollup the daily sales data (qauntity and unit price) to monthly level, for each customer .The following is the input Data format

**Columns:**

1) StockCode

2) Quantity

3) InvoiceDate

4) UnitPrice

Here the data is visible for StockCode ABCD at daily level.For example StockCode ABCD is sold 50 Kg on Day 1 with unit price of 50 per kg.

What I need to find is the monthly qauntity of StockCode ABCD sold , with its unit price and month being visible.

**I have tried the following code:**

```
ShortRetail <- retail %>% group_by (Date = floor_date(retail$InvoiceDate, "month"),retail$StockCode) %>% summarise(Qty_sum= sum(retail$Quantity))
```

**Expected columns:**

1) Stock Code

2) Quantity

3) Invoice Month

4) Unit Price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good start! Just need to include the price in the pipe... but also, a good tip is to take things more slowly, in more steps. Since you've already called `retail` you don't need to do `retail$` later in the pipe... so try something like this (tho I can't test it because I don't have your code).

```
ShortRetail <- retail %>% 
  mutate(Date = floor_date(InvoiceDate, "month")) %>%
  group_by (Date, StockCode) %>% 
  summarise(Qty_sum= sum(Quantity),
            Ave_price = mean(Price))
```